# Why selector is not working for different jms listeners in spring

Tags: spring-jms

I am using spring jms listener to consume messages
here is my sample code:

```
<jms:listener id="skpListener" destination="ASYNC_SKP_MSG_QUEUE" ref="skpRequestListener" selector="${jms.consumer.listener.selector}" concurrency="2-10"/>
    <jms:listener id="updateBoxListner" destination="ASYNC_UPDATEBOX_QUEUE" ref="updateBoxRequestListener" selector="${jms.consumer.listener.selector}" concurrency="2-10" />
    <jms:listener id="e2eListener" destination="ASYNC_E2E_UPDATE_QUEUE" ref="e2eDashRequestListener" selector="${jms.consumer.listener.selector}" concurrency="2-10"/>
    <jms:listener id="replListener" destination="ASYNC_SKP_REPL_MSG_QUEUE" ref="skpReplRequestListener" selector="${jms.consumer.listener.selector}" concurrency="2-10"/>
```

Here for the first listener, selector is working properly. But for the second listener selector is not fired with given selector string.

Can any one help me to find out any other configuration

Comment: You need to show the property values.

Comment: the property value is: jms.consumer.listener.selector :: jmsTargetHostName = 'IM01211013278.infics.com:8080'

Comment: Selector is working for "skpRequestListener" but not "updateBoxRequestListener" probably it same for other two listeners.

Comment: Makes no sense to me, given they all have the same selector; sorry.

Comment: Though I am giving different selector, still it is not filtering

Comment: Identified the issue. It is the Oracle JMS Q creation problem. For two destinations, there is a same table. Because of this skpRequestListener is working fine and updateBoxRequestListener is not working.